# Unbinding event that has been bound mutliple times

Tags: jquery

There are two js scripts that bind to `$(window).scroll()`. In one script (example1.js) I have the need to unbind the event (or find an acceptable alternative) when certain criteria is met, but this causes the `.scroll()` event to be completely unbound, removing all functionality.

What I would like to do is, once the criteria has been met, stop the scroll event from firing for example1.js but not for example2.js.

example1.js

```
function exampleFunction(self) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 364) {
            self.start();
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: self.settings.dataUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (json) {
            if (json.data.length) {
                self.json = json;
                self.addImages();
            } else {
                $(window).unbind('scroll');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

example2.js

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    someFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Namespaced Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events). This will allow you to namespace an event and then unbind only that namespace, leaving other bindings intact.

For Example:

```
// Create Bindings //
$(window).bind('scroll.example1', function(e){
    ...
});

$(window).bind('scroll.example2', function(e){
    ...
});

// Unbind ONLY .example1 Namespace //
$(window).unbind('scroll.example1');
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use [**namespaced**](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) event when binding the event.

**Example:**

```
//bind click.a
$('.class').on('click.a', function(){ alert ('inside a space'); }); 
//bind click.b
$('.class').on('click.b', function(){ alert ('inside b space'); }); 

//unbind click.b
$('.class').off('click.b');

//trigger click.a
$('.class').trigger('click.a');
```

In your case,

**example1.js**

```
function exampleFunction(self) {
    $(window).on('scroll.e1', function () {  //bind scroll.e1
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 364) {
            self.start();
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: self.settings.dataUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (json) {
            if (json.data.length) {
                self.json = json;
                self.addImages();
            } else {
                $(window).unbind('scroll.e1'); //unbind scroll.e1
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**example2.js**

```
$(window).on('scroll.e2', function () { //bind scroll.e2
    someFunction();
});
```